# AR Core changes to be visible in play store

Tags: android, arcore

I made an android app with ar core functions.
The app can be found in the playstore with newer smartphones, Android 7+ but not all smartphone can find the app.

min. SDK Version is 24 and target version 28.

Now my question:

all smartphones should be able to download the app and use it but without ar core functionality.

Is it enough to set the min sdk version lower or is it necessary to delete all ar core codes?

Comment: you can check android version at runtime to enable the fonctionnality or disable it

Comment: thanks for your reply, how can i check it?

Comment: if you don't have a device to test this, you can setup an emulator with an older android version

Comment: do you have this tags in you AndroidManifest.xml?  Can you post your manifest ?

    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar"
            android:required="true" />

or 

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.ar.core"
                android:value="required" />